# MySQL:How to sort date with RFC112 format?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, format, sql-order-by

For example, I have a column named `date` on my table `post` and I want to sort it in `ascending`.

On my `date` column I fill it with *RCF112* format, eg: `Sun, 22 APR 2012 5:21:22`.

First I begin with this command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  post 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

But the result appears to be incorrect because it was sorted according to its string, eg. the `Sun, 15 APR 2012` will be older than `Wed,11 APR 2012` because "Sun" starts with 'S' which is in alphabetic ahead 'W', so the "Sun, 15 APR 2012"  appears first.

How to correct this command?

Comment: what is the data type of `date` column?

Comment: @sarwar026: I use varchar, is it incorrect?

Comment: yes, it should be of DATETIME datatype. Please try it and then check again.

Comment: I use DATETIME datatype already. But the problem is, I got an error each time I insert a data. "Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'date' at row 1"

Comment: That error means you're inserting data that is in the wrong format -- the format MySQL's DATETIME column expects is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. So transform your data into that format on insertion, and then sorting on it will Just Work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the string as datetime to be able to sort it correctly.

Using your format, you can try something like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('Sun, 22 APR 2012 5:21:22', '%a, %e %b %Y %h:%i:%S')
```

which creates the date `2012-04-22 05:21:22`.

So, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  post 
ORDER BY 
  STR_TO_DATE(date, '%a, %e %b %Y %h:%i:%S')
ASC
```

As others might have already suggested, you could use the `datetime` field type and format the date in the select (`date_format` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to fit your requirements.

Comment: The names of day and month are abbreviated so your format mask is incorrect.

Comment: @Ben You are right, I will update the answer to use abbreviations instead. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  post 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datestr, '%a, %d %b %Y %T') ASC
```